# Exclude a schema property in response json body of OpenApi

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenApi 3.0 yaml file to generate the java code for handling the REST requests. The below is the related snippet of the yaml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: v0
  /users/get-user-by-name:
    get:
      tags:
        - user-controller
      operationId: getUser
      parameters:
        - name: username
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
components:
    schemas:
        privateinfo:
          type: object
          properties:
            connection:
              type: string
            user_id:
              type: string
            isSocial:
              type: boolean
            uniq_id:
              type: string
          required:
            - connection
            - user_id
            - isSocial
        User:
          type: object
          properties:
            username:
              type: string
            email:
              type: string
            email_verified:
              type: boolean
            user_id:
              type: string
            name:
              type: string
            privateinfo:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/privateinfo'
```

Adding the 'required:' has no effect.
How do i exclude the `'uniq_id'` field in the response body for the API Endpoint?
if there is no particular way to exclude the `'uniq_id'` field, then is there a way to send `"NA"` or some equivalent string in place of the actual value without modifying the java code? Example:

```
    { 
        ... 
        "uniq_id":"NA" 
        ... 
    }
```

Comment: this is something you would handle in your java code. You can decide if you want to send any optional property based on the request received.

Comment: please paste the whole definition, you have references to other components and it is hard to understand the model you are using without those definitions

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, you should exclude the field you want on runtime based on some filter criteria you are passing. Still, if your API design architect already set the contract for your clients (external customers or internal applications) you should follow that contract. You should probably get the business requirements to see if it makes sense to send NA as you suggest.
But any rest API should have a shaping capability, where the client decides as well which field they want to consume from your response. For example, OData follows this pattern

https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$select=CategoryName

Where they select CategoryName only, in your case you can select the fields you want but your backend should be responsible on runtime to return the data needed. Using Reflection on your code will help you to achieve this.

In your case, you are sending an array of privateinfo objects as part of the response "User", which is a nested collection, that you are returning, be careful there with that design as well, your API designer should consider creating another route to return those elements in case the data is big (privateinfo ~ 1 million records) can hurt your response time, your consumer will suffer as well to load them without a proper pagination in place